# Graphical Layout Preview fails

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created an registration form with EditTextfields and one CustomAutoCompletField that is used for autocomplete places which will be received from the google places api. Before I implemented this AutoCompleteTextView the graphical layout preview worked fine.

**Here the error message that I always get:**

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'autoCompleteTextViewStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_firstname
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_lastname
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_username
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_email
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_password
Couldn't resolve resource @string/EditText_residence
Couldn't resolve resource @string/btn_register
Couldn't resolve resource @string/login
```

**Here the layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_firstname"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_lastname"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_username"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <com.autocomplete.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/atv_places"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/EditText_residence" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="@string/btn_register"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bktologin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here the CustomAutoCompleteTextView Java class:**

```
/** Customizing AutoCompleteTextView to return Place Description
 * corresponding to the selected item
 */
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("description");
    }

}
```

**And also my Theme definition:**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#5C5C5C</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Did you choose Theme in Eclipse? http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ik1A.png

Comment: Ok I solved this issue by adding a default "values" and put styles.xml in it. I have two more values folders to support more languages. I do not know but I think the layout file could not reference properly to one of the "values" folders.